# Restrict certain page requests from certain referrals (nginx)

Tags: nginx

Is there a way in nginx to deny access to specific sections of the website based on a referral ?

Basically trying to block access to 2 directories from 2 referrer domains.

Here is the code I am using:

```
if ( ($http_referer ~* (badomain1.com|badomain2.com)) && 
     ($request_uri ~* (directory1/|directory2/))
   ) {
    return 403;
}
```

But nginx fails with error:

[emerg]: invalid condition "($http_referer" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:88
configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to escape the dot like so: \.

Then return 444, it's nginx internal for don't answer at all.

```
if ($http_referer ~* (babes|click|diamond|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|organic|poker|porn|poweroversoftware|sex|teen|video|webcam|zippo) ) {
    return 444;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Nginx "if" statement is not the same as "if" in a scripting language such as PHP. It is just a rewrite directive.

You cannot have something like

```
if *expression1* OR *expression2* then
    *code*
end
```

You need to do

```
if *expression1* then
    *Rewrite Directive Only*
end
if *expression2* then
    *Rewrite Directive Only*
end
```

To do

```
if *expression1* AND *expression2* then
    *code*
end
```

You need to do

```
if *expression1* then
    set $myVar X;
end
if *expression2* then
    set $myVar $myVarX;
end
if $myVar = XX then
    *Rewrite Directive Only*
end
```

It is important to note that "if" in Nginx is simply a rewrite directive and that this means that only other rewrite directives should go into `*code*`. "Return" and "Set" are valid rewrite directives.

I use a similar setup to filter requests and actually taken it up one level by using Lua to evaluate via the Lua module.

```
if (*expression1* OR *expression2*) AND (*expression3* OR *expression4*) then
    *Complex Code*
end
```

Comment: But in this case both expressions would not be met ? it would be like OR ?

Comment: Expanded the answer accordingly